# Filtered / CachedRowSets and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jdbc, jsf-2, primefaces

Clearly I am missing something.  What I read about RowSets(Cached/Filtered/Joined) is that they are Beans capable.

So, on my .xhtml, I have the following kind of code, and I am using PrimeFaces 5.x

```
...
<p:dataTabel var="aRow" value="#{pageBean.List<Type>}">

<p:column value="#{aRow.property}" / >;

...

</p:dataTable>
```

If I use one of the RowSets to fetch my data, where do I define it so that I can access it without having to copy everything into Lists ?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: `pageBean.List<Type>`? "*Where do I define it so that I can access it without having to **copy everything into Lists**?*"

Comment: PrimeFaces 5.x is to generic. And I've never seen a `#{pageBean.List<Type>}`

Comment: Are you using plain jdbc? If using jpa, 'results' already **are** `List<Type>`

Comment: @Tiny: I think you wrongfully removed the jdbc tag

Comment: Right but JDBC or not the method to iterate over a collection using an iterating JSF/PrimeFaces component is no loner different. Apart from that  using a `java.sql.ResultSet` directly with an iterating component which in turn is not serializable and requires an open JDBC connection is something deemed unhelpful and should always be avoided. @Kukeltje

Comment: @Tiny: Everything has its downside ;-) but a CachedRowSet dos not need an open connection (See [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) [Oracle Intro](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html) and  [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074942/jndi/get-disconnected-with-cachedrowset.html) and can be serialized... (see javaworld, specs and 'intro')

Comment: @Kukeltje : I did not know about that feature of `CachedRowSet`. Thank you. (The JavaWorld article is quite old (Feb 2, 2001) but it still holds some useful info).

Comment: @Tiny: Articles about the middleages are even older and even they still hold value ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The PrimeFaces datatable at this time of writing (5.2) does not support this. The reason for this is outlined in the link below, but it boils down to the fact that the current implementation of the PF datatable needs the total 'rowcount' and a rowset does not support this.

**See also**

- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4500